# Reading from file into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

guys.
I have a trouble reading from file in C and putting in into array, assigning each part of an array to an variable.

The file looks like this:

```
A0005:Burger:2.39:Extra Cheese
A0006:Soda:1.35:Coke
....
```

The thing is, I don't quite get how do you split string in C when it reaches colon.

So far i tried to make a structure, tried using strtok and getchar but so far unsuccessfully.

here's what i got so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct menuItems{
 char itemCode[5];
 char itemName[50];
 float itemPrice;
 char itemDetails[50];
 };


int main(void){
    FILE *menuFile;
    char line[255];
    char c;

    struct menuItems allMenu = {"","",0.0,""};


    if ((menuFile = fopen("addon.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        puts("File could not be opened.");

    }
    else{
        printf("%-6s%-16s%-11s%10s\n", "Code", "Name", "Price", "Details");
        while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), menuFile) != NULL ){
            c = getchar();
            while(c !='\n' && c != EOF){
                fscanf(menuFile, "%5s[^:]%10s[^:]%f[^:]%s[^:]", allMenu.itemCode, allMenu.itemName, &allMenu.itemPrice, allMenu.itemDetails);
            }

            }


    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to store the retrieved elements from all the lines?

Comment: I want to store it in the structure so later on i can use it

Answer (score 1):

For every line you need to do something like:

```
   /* your code till fgets followed by following */
   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(line, ":");

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token ); /* you would rather store these in array or whatever you want to do with it. */

      token = strtok(NULL, ":");
   }
```

The following code allocates memory for an array of 100 menuItems and reads the given file entries into it. You can actually count the number of lines in your input file and allocate as many entries (instead of hard coded 100):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct menuItem
{
    char itemCode[5];
    char itemName[50];
    float itemPrice;
    char itemDetails[50];
};

int main()
{
    char line[255];
    FILE *menuFile = fopen("addon.txt", "r");
    struct menuItem * items =
        (struct menuItem *) malloc (100 * sizeof (struct menuItem));
    struct menuItem * mem = items;

    while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), menuFile) != NULL )
    {
        char *token = strtok(line, ":");
        assert(token != NULL);
        strcpy(items->itemCode, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        assert(token != NULL);
        strcpy(items->itemName, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        assert(token != NULL);
        items->itemPrice = atof(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        assert(token != NULL);
        strcpy(items->itemDetails, token);
        items++;
   }

   free(mem);
   fclose(menuFile);
}
```

Comment: how do you exactly store it in array, that what i cant get. In python i would use list of lists, not sure how to implement it here

Comment: you can use an array of your struct menuItems

Comment: thats the thing, when i scan file with fscanf, it doesnt scan it properly.

Comment: You don't have to scan the file. You can continue using fgets. Please check a code block that I added above to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Build succeeds but i get assertion error at the second assert(token != NULL)

Comment: @IvanTarabykin: what is the content of your addon.txt file? I had put in what you specified in your question.

Comment: `char itemCode[5];` --> `char itemCode[5+1];`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: that is better. I did not make that change in my code since Ivan did not have that in his original code.

Comment: It must be modified as it causes buffer overruns.